# Responsive design of two-column table

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have a small table in the form of a bullet list with two columns. When displaying on mobile, I would like to collapse it into one column:

[image: Small table]

I have currently implemented it like this:

```
<style>
@media (min-width: 600px)
{
  ul > li > span
  {
    display: inline-block;
    width:   250px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 599px)
{
  ul > li > span:first-child
  {
    display: block;
  }
}
</style>

<ul>
  <li><span>E-mail:</span> <span><a href="mailto:abc@xyz.se">abc@xyz.se</a></span>
  <li><span>Telefon:</span> <span><a href="tel:+46701234567">070-123 45 67</a></span>
  <li><span>Adress:</span> <span>Föreningen XYZ</span><br>
  <span></span> <span>Storgatan 1</span><br>
  <span></span> <span>123 45 Småstad</span>
  <li><span>Swish:</span> <span><a href="tel://1234567890">123-456 78 90</a></span>
  <li><span>Bankgiro:</span> <span><a href="tel://1234–5678">1234-5678</a></span>
</ul>
```

But I do not like the hardcoded widths of the columns - I would like it to be based on the contents. I have another small table where the second column uses `text-align: right` but should be left-aligned when collapsed. And my solution is not very elegant, I would prefer not using media queries if possible.

I have been looking into using Flexbox but I can't get it to work the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

Mark it up in your HTML as a [description list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl), then style it as a responsive grid for wider screens.

When you run this snippet, make sure you use the **full page** link and adjust the width of your browser window to test the responsive behaviour.

```css
/* mobile-first design. base styles implement the mobile layout. */

dt::before {
  content: '• ';
}

dd {
  margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
}

/* add overrides for wider screens in increasing order of width */

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  dl {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    gap: 1em;
  }

  dd {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>E-mail:</dt>
  <dd><a href="mailto:abc@xyz.se">abc@xyz.se</a></dd>

  <dt>Telefon:</dt>
  <dd><a href="tel:+46701234567">070-123 45 67</a></dd>

  <dt>Adress:</dt>
  <dd>Föreningen XYZ<br>Storgatan 1<br>123 45 Småstad</dd>

  <dt>Swish:</dt>
  <dd><a href="tel://1234567890">123-456 78 90</a></dd>

  <dt>Bankgiro:</dt>
  <dd><a href="tel://1234–5678">1234-5678</a></dd>
</dl>
```